# .delay() random number between times

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for some help with jQuery's .delay function. I have a popup form on my site that I want to pop up randomly between 2-3 minutes. I understand how to use Math.random(), but I don't understand how to use it to generate a number between 120000ms and 180000ms. Here is my current code set for two minutes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#popup-main').hide().delay(120000).fadeIn(500)
});
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var min = 120000, max = 180000;
    var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

    $('#popup-main').hide().delay(delay).fadeIn(500)
});
```

Or if you want more even numbers:

```
var min = 12, max = 18;
var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min) * 10000;
```

Answer (score 1):

You understand Math.random(), so you know that it returns a value between 0 and 1. If you multiply that value by your minimum (120000) you'll get a value between 0 and 120000. If you instead multiply it by 180000, you'll get a value between 0 and 180000. If you instead multiply it by 180000 - 120000, you'll get a value between 0 and 60000. Then you can add that to 120000 and you'll get a number within your desired range.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way; you have a "base" of 120000 (two minutes) and you just randomize the rest 60000 (one minute).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60000) + 120000;
    $('#popup-main').hide().delay(delay).fadeIn(500)
});
```